# Getting VLC and Remmina working together

Tags: vlc, freerdp, remmina

I've installed Remmina on Linux Mint 17.2, which was working great.

Then I wanted to use VLC, but it wasn't installed. After struggling a bit to install VLC, it was finally working. However, Remmina stopped working, as the RDP plugin was missing.

Re-installing the RDP protocol fixed Remmina, but broke VLC...

Is there a way to get these 2 working at the same time?